# hackrf and gnuradio 3.7 making a signal generator

Tags: gnuradio, hackrf

I am trying to make a signal generator utilizing gnuradio and hackrf osmocom but it doesnt want to execute [image]

Comment: Hi Markl17! Welcome here. GNU Radio 3.7 has long reached its end of life, meaning that within the GNU Radio community, knowledge on how to even use it is dwindling, and also, that absolutely no effort is made to make it run on modern machines. You're in unsupported territory! Before you learn how to use GNU Radio, I'd **strongly** recommend you install a modern version of it – not only because it'll be possible for people to help you, but also because there's been so so many improvements that will make your life easier. Especially installation has gotten easy!

Comment: yes I know that 3.7 is very old and hackrf is no longer supported but 3.10  supports sopay devices with out any real support. hackrf was able to  be used as a signal generator which costs 50000 but hackrf is about 150

Comment: What do you mean with "no real support"? We have put and continue to put much support into gr-soapysdr, and so do the folks behind SoapySDR, and also GreatScottGadgets have an employee who's especially concerned with soapy-hackrf working well.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Radio 3.7 has long reached its end of life, meaning that within the GNU Radio community, knowledge on how to even use it is dwindling, and also, that absolutely no effort is made to make it run on modern machines. (There's just not much GNU Radio can do – 3.7 relies on obsolete things, and we can't make these work on modern machines. Plus, people are working on making GNU Radio more usable and useful – that conflicts with the time they can spend on making old things work.)

So: With the GNU Radio you're using, you're in unsupported territory! I was the GNU Radio head maintainer for three years, and even I can't help you with GNU Radio 3.7 on Windows. Sorry.

Before you learn how to use GNU Radio, I'd **strongly** recommend you install a modern version of it – not only because it'll be possible for people to help you, all the newly created documentation applies to you, but also because there's been so so many improvements that will make your life easier. Especially installation has gotten easy!

You can just download the officially supported radioconda installer([current version](https://github.com/ryanvolz/radioconda/releases/download/2022.09.22/radioconda-2022.09.22-Windows-x86_64.exe) as of 2022-11-25, for future versions, check [the newest entry here](https://github.com/ryanvolz/radioconda/releases) and select "radioconda-DATE-Windows.x86_64.exe" under "All Assets"), run it, and then you have a working GNU Radio Companion right in your start menu. To make your HackRF work you then would also need to follow [this](https://github.com/ryanvolz/radioconda#installing-the-winusb-driver-with-zadig), i.e., [download the Zadig driver installer](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/releases/download/v1.4.1/zadig-2.7.exe) and select your hackrf there, and click "Install driver".

Afterwards, the HackRF can be directly used in your GNU Radio flow graph – search for "hackrf" in the block library (it's the "Soapy HackRF sink" that you need).

Connect your "Signal Source" to the "Soapy HackRF sink", set the samp_rate to "1e6". (I'm not sure the HackRF even supports 100 kHz of sampling rate, you'd notice by the wrong frequencies.)
Then click on generate and run.

PS: Modern GNU Radio Companion has a "Screen Capture" button, so you don't have to take photos with a camera :)

PS2: official pictured GNU Radio tutorials are on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org ; they're actually quite nice. People, and especially highly motivated and even more experienced hams put a lot of work in there (especially KV4FV did, a lot, and I'm eternally thankful!), and I think it addresses what you'd like to know to get started pretty well, if you read it from the beginning :)

PS3: The GNU Radio community has a nice amateur radio operator chat room. Might be worth saying hello in there! It's easy to access, just go [here](https://app.element.io/#/room/#HamRadio:gnuradio.org), click on the "Sign Up" link in the bottom right (you don't have to enter any personal information but a username of your choice – callsigns work well) and then you'll be chatting with fellow GNU Radio-using hams.

Comment: I tried th3 gnuradio 2.9 it has whole new slew of soapy hackrf which I down even have a clue how to make work for what I need

Comment: believe me I really tried to make hackrf work with it I dont know how to set up those hackrf osmocom device related things in new version if you have ideas I am all ears on how if now then lets deal with the 3.7 that I was finally was able to download and make work i.e. executable. so yes if you make adiveces please make more useful onces besides why dont you switch to a never version. I tried

Comment: You don't need osmosdr anymore for modern GNU Radio, as I wrote, it's all built in now - and as s sorry as I am, starting with GNU Radio 3.7 is simply not where you should be. That makes more problems than it solves, which is why I wrote this lengthy answer! I don't know what you tried to install GNU Radio 3.10, but that download I linked you to is going to work on windows. Full stop.

Comment: So, as literally the person who made the executive decisions on how long we can try to make 3.7 survive, I can tell you with authority that GNU Radio 3.7 is not the solution. Sorry, really!

Comment: (it's really not that we didn't *want* to support 3.7 anymore. It was just technically impossible. It's dead.)

Comment: I am trying to use hackrf as a signal source. I was able to do that during gnuradio 3.7 using osmocom which is no longer available on 3.10 because it is replaced by soapy hackrf. I was able to load osmocom to install but it does not load the whole thing claiming that qtgui is not able to be loaded. did anyone use osmocom as a source to generate frequencies from 10mhz till 6 ghz in 1 hz steps, please provide examples of how-to setup one.

[https://imgur.com/a/iTpkbuZ]it is osmocom,in 3.10 to me this example sounds alright but again i just followed the gist on the youtube of someone else.